# Onpress is not calling the function to change the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am using React Native.I am trying to change the button when it is clicked. I want to show the add item component by default and when it is clicked I want it to change to remove item.

```
const Products = () => {
const [added,notAdd]=useState(false);
 function changeIT(){
        console.log(added);
        notAdd(!added);
        console.log(added);
        
    }
return (
{added?<Remove index={index} onPress={()=>changeIT()}/> :<Add item={item} onPress={()=>changeIT()}/> }
)}
```

Nothing happens after I click on the buttons.

Comment: onPress doesn't work like that inside a new component, you have to do it also in Remove component

Comment: "Nothing happens" - So you don't see any logs either?

Comment: Are you calling the onPress prop inside the Add and Remove component? Can you also include the Remove and Add component code ?

Comment: Check either `onPress` is triggering or not. show the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have only included the `onPress` event when the component is being executed, not in the actual component itself, for example.

Execution:

```
<Add item={item} onPress={()=>changeIT()}/>
```

Declaration:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Pressable, Text} from 'react-native';

export default function Add({ item , onPress}) {

  return (
    <Pressable onPress={onPress}> 
      <Text>Add</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
}
```

Comment: It worked but I now have two functions to call when im clicking the touchable I am trying to add both of them to the onPress but it does'nt seem to work?-

```
onPress={()=>{
      addItem(item);
      onPress;
    }}>
```
This is in the add.js file

Comment: If Possible please provide complete code to solve your issue.